# Use Shared Object Data() or Shared Object Property() to store value

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, shared-objects

I'm confused. SharedObject seems have two ways to store value in it, by data and setProperty():

```
so.data.foo = 'bar';

so.setProperty('boo', 'bar');
```

What's the different? And why doesn't it have getProperty()?

Comment: This needs more context. What language / platform is this? What's `SharedObject`?

Comment: Hi Millimoose, Thanks for your reply. Okay, I am using ActionScript 3.0 A shared object is similiar to a browser cookie however, they are not stored with the rest of your browsers cookies and are not deleted when the user deletes the regular cookies. I am just trying to save some data about clients.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`SharedObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#setProperty%28%29) reference: `setProperty()` marks a property as "dirty" in addition to setting it, which you need to do if you're using a remote `SharedObject`, as it tells the server that the value needs to be updated in other clients.

It's slightly more convenient than manually setting the property and then calling `setDirty()`, and there's obviously no need to for a similar `getProperty()` method, as the server doesn't need to be informed when you do that.

Comment: Thank You David for the explanation. That's all i needed to know. Cheers!